# htaccess will not get variable

Tags: apache, .htaccess, variables, get

First of all this code is working on my previous shared host  now I'm moving to vps with ubuntu 16.04, php7, apache 2.4.18
this is my htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ya/(.*) ya.php?var=$1
```

my php code

```
$theya = $_REQUEST['var'];
```

When this working let's say people type http://mysite.coco/ya/ct1234
it will catch the var "ct1234".

I can echo it just fine

```
<?php echo"$theya"; ?>
```

Now it won't... Is my code incompatible with the apache or php7?

Thank you

edit: a wordpress with permalinks can run just fine on this server.

Comment: Use this line in your htaccess `Options -Multiviews`

Answer (score 0):

Is .htaccess enabled for your directory at your shared hosting provider? At least [AllowOverride](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/de/mod/core.html#allowoverride) FileInfo  should be set for your directory in the Apache Config.

P.S. Please never echo user input without escaping/encoding, would be a possible XSS otherwise.